# PCL - Not able to generate binary for people_pcd_prob.cpp in ubuntu

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have installed PCL and it dependency library and successfully generated
Make and installed PCL library file, But I am not able to generate
people_pcd_prob.cpp binary after enable

```
BUILD_CUDA - ON 
BUILD_GPU  - ON  
BUILD_people  - ON                                                                                                                                                                 
CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR - /usr/local/cuda                                                                                                                                                 
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR  - /usr/local/cuda
```

Build success with out error, But binary for people_pcd_probe binary is not generate. I want to use this binary for PCD file as input and provide skeleton tracking . Reference url : https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl

CMake Generated log :

```
-- The following subsystems will not be built:
--   gpu_tracking: Disabled by default.
--   gpu_surface: Disabled by default.
--   gpu_people: Disabled by default.
--   cuda_io: Disabled by default.
--   cuda_apps: Disabled: cuda_io missing.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Comment: Did you run first cmake and then make?

Comment: Yes I have configured ccmake .. then make ,it generated binary in bin  inside build folder , but people binary not generated

Comment: Is there is any specific configuration need to setup other than above mentioned option ?